# Selectively inherit in a child class in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have the following classes defined:

```
class First(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("first")

    def mF1(self):
        print "first 1"

    def mF2(self):
        print "first 2"


class Second(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("second")

    def mS1(self):
        print "second 1"


class Third(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("third")

    def mT1(self):
        print "third 1"

    def mT2(self):
        print "third 2"

    def mT3(self):
        print "third 3"


class Fourth(First, Second, Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print("fourth")


C = Fourth()
C.mF1()
C.mF2()
C.mS1()
C.mT1()
C.mT2()
C.mT3()
```

Which gives the output:

```
first
fourth
first 1
first 2
second 1
third 1
third 2
third 3
```

With this, it is pretty clear that all the attributes and methods of classes `First`, `Second`, `Third` and `Fourth` is available in the class `Fourth`.
Now, I would like class `Fourth` to selectively inherit from parents based on the context - i.e., from `First` alone or from `First` and `Third` etc. One way is to have separate classes defined as follows:

```
class Fourth1(First):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print("fourth first")


class Fourth2(First, Third):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Fourth, self).__init__()
        print("fourth first third")
```

which means having separate classes defined and having separate class names instead of one.

I want to know if there is an easier, dynamic and "pythonic" way to achieve this? Is it possible to choose where to inherit (just like `super()` does, inherit all attributes and methods including the private methods) from in a simple way like say,

```
C = Fourth(1,0,0)
```

to inherit from `First` and

```
C = Fourth(1,0,1)
```

to inherit from `First` and `Third`?

Comment: Isn't a class that inherits from all classes as suitable for you need as one that only inherits from one or two? Or in other words: [if it quacks like a duck, it is a duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). What does it matter if it can bark as well?

Comment: @KlausD. I understand your point. But if the code base is huge, having a lot of unwanted things might burden the system resources, doesn't it?

Comment: Only if you run code from that "unwanted" classes.

Comment: Noted. That was enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done via `__new__`. Because it is possible to dynamically create classes inheriting from other classes, and `__new__` can create objects of arbitrary types:

```
class Fourth(object):
    """BEWARE special class that creates objects of subclasses"""
    classes = [None] * 8

    def __new__(cls, first, second, third):
        index = 1 if first else 0
        index += 2 if second else 0
        index += 4 if third else 0
        if not cls.classes[index]:
            parents = [Fourth]
            if first: parents.append(First)
            if second: parents.append(Second)
            if third: parents.append(Third)
            ns = {'__new__': object.__new__,
                  '__init__': Fourth._child__init__,
                  '__doc__': Fourth.__doc__}
            cls.classes[index] = type('Fourth', tuple(parents), ns)
        return object.__new__(cls.classes[index])

    def _child__init__(self, first = None, second=None, third=None):
        Fourth.__init__(self)

    def __init__(self):
        print("Fourth")
```

After that you can do what you wanted:

```
>>> c = Fourth(1,0,0)
Fourth
>>> c2 = Fourth(1,1,1)
Fourth
>>> c
<__main__.Fourth1 object at 0x0000024026151780>
>>> c2
<__main__.Fourth7 object at 0x000002402616E8D0>
>>> c2.mT1()
third 1
>>> c.mT1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#302>", line 1, in <module>
    c.mT1()
AttributeError: 'Fourth1' object has no attribute 'mT1'
```

But I strongly advise you against that hack unless you have important reasons to do so. Because it ends in having a class (`Fourth`) that creates objects not from itself but from subclasses. And object apparently belonging to that class will have different behaviour. This will disturb future readers and maintainers

Comment: Okay. This looks satisfying. So, you too suggest like @Klaus D. to inherit from all the parent classes as a safe bet instead of implementing this way?

Comment: @skrowten_hermit: Implementing this way is nice for the fun. But I would never use it in production grade code. I cannot find a real world reason for that, so I do agree with Klaus: object created via a class should belong to that class, so it will be safer (and easier to maintain) to inherit from all the parent classes.